# export jobs from talend DI to talend big data

Tags: hadoop, etl, talend, data-integration, bigdata

I am new to talend ETL tool.I have created jobs workflow in talend DI(data integration) tool now I want to switch/implement same jobs using hadoop for that I am using talend Big Data tool. Can anybody explain me how could I achieve this. Talend DI to Talend Big Data integration.

Comment: Did you try the `Export` and `Import` buttons in the toolbar?

Comment: Yes, I checked that also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding liberaries are different for both DI and Big Data Talend tool may be because of this import is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Talend checks the version of the enviromeent before importing items, you can dodge it by deleting the `talend.project` file from the exported directory or archive.

Answer (score 0):

I have had success with editing the talend.project file so the version shown matches the one you are trying to import TO (if they are different). 
I imagine this may not always work if you are using components or features that are not compatible with the target version.